# Installing Standard Ruby Classes Documentation with rdoc3

Tags: ruby, documentation

What is the correct procedure to have the standard Ruby class documentation available via the "ri" system?  I know about the rdoc-data gem, but is that still appropriate for the rdoc3 (3.0.1) gem?

Ruby 1.8.7/Linux (OS) specific if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you install via a package manager, or did you build from source? If building from source, did you run the `make` command for the documentation?

Comment: Package manager.  Ubuntu 10.10 (64bit).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up installing the `rdoc-data` gem and ran:

```
rdoc-data --install
```

(after creating `/usr/share/ri`) and it all seems to work.  It would be nice if there was a way to install the documentation to somewhere *other* than `/usr/share/ri` but at least the docs are available.